# Freeswitch Originate and session heartbeat

Tags: freeswitch

I would like to know how to set the per call heartbeat events to be able to capture the event because I have subscribed to the event SESSION_HEARTBEAT. So far I just subscribed to that event but I cannot capture the event when I made a call.

Please assit.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend: https://www.mail-archive.com/freeswitch-users@lists.freeswitch.org/msg17769.html

`enable_heartbeat` application exists in the source code, but is somehow missing in the Wiki.

Comment: I do know about the enable_heartbeat. What I am asking is how to set when making a call from ESL. I do not want to set it in a dialplan.